# How can I make sass work in react js project?

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass, npm-install, node-sass

print screen from my vs with react and sass:

[image]

I have a project in react, almost everything works well, the localhost displays my content, but it looks like it is not reading my scss files, the page has no style and everything has no alignment. Do you know what can be the problem here? I installed the npm install node-sass, but still no change. I even runned the Watch Sass on the files but only style.scss worked. What can be written wrong, or should I add something more somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot alone, I think you forgot to import the style.scss, not sure if you did on index.js.

Comment: I have it, now it says that Node Sass version 6.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0.

Comment: remove your current one and install version 5 or 4
,
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/node+sass+version+6.0.0+is+incompatible+with+4.0.0

Comment: Thank you very much and I appreciate your help, now it works perfectly fine with what u said!!